# Plotting Vertical Asymptotes

Tags: plotting

The following code produces the graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ correctly.

```
 Plot[1/(x - 1), {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 Exclusions -> {x - 1 == 0}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

However, when I try to graph $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ with essentially the same code, I lose the vertical asymptote.

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
Exclusions -> {(x - 1)^2 == 0}, 
ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image]

I have tried all sorts of permutations of writing the exclusions, but nothing seems to work!  From what I can tell, whenever I try to graph a rational function that has a factor in the denominator with an even power, the vertical asymptote fails to draw.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like `Exclusion` "connects" your singularities... So in the first case it connects two points $(1,-\infty)$ and $(1,+\infty)$, in the second case there is just one point $(1,+\infty)$, so no line is visible...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a good demonstration of how `ExclusionsStyle` works [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExclusionsStyle.html). Check
`Plot[Floor[x], {x, 0, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`

If you use the second form of `ExclusionsStyle`, you will see the points (boundary of exclusion region) that are being connected by your asymptote:

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^3, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 25}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 Exclusions -> {x - 1 == 0}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], 
   Directive[PointSize -> 0.05, Green]}]
```

[image: plot with asymptote]

When you have even powers, those two points degenerate into one point and your line becomes invisible.

[image: no asymptote]

A possible workaround would be drawing the line separately with `Epilog` or `ListPlot`

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Line[{{1, -1000}, {1, 1000}}]}]
```

Or

```
Show[Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}], 
 ListPlot[{{1, -1000}, {1, 1000}}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]]
```

Or per Kuba's comment:

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
 GridLines -> {{1}, None}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```

[image: alternative]

In the most general case, when your asymptote isn't horizontal or vertical, you will need to plot it as a separate plot. So `Exclusions` is not the best option:

```
Plot[{4/(x^2 + 1) + x, x}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, Directive[Red, Dashed]},  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image: oblique asymptote]

Comment: Fantastic! I had no idea that this was how ExclusionStyle worked! I learned two things from this massive headache!

Comment: `GridLines` are also an option.

Comment: @Kuba... I like `GridLines` idea, edited the answer.

Comment: @Kuba on the other hand the `GridLines` won't work if the asymptote isn't vertical or horizontal...

Comment: @BlacKow, yes, for that you can either plot the oblique asymptote as a separate function, or use `InfiniteLine[]` in `Epilog`.

Comment: These are all fantastic! For some odd reason, it never occurred to me to just plot the asymptote separately....

Comment: @BlacKow they can't do many things but they are the solution in context of the title :)

Comment: @J.M. Didn't see your comment before posting an answer... InfiniteLine is indeed very convenient for this.

Comment: s'okay @Szabolcs, I guess it's good to have it as an explicit answer. One once needed an external package to do what `InfiniteLine[]` does today... :D

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness: before `InfiniteLine[]` came along, I often used `Scaled[]` in conjunction with `Line[]` to depict horizontal and vertical asymptotes.

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, Axes -> True,
     Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed],
                Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}, {1, 0}], Scaled[{0, -1}, {1, 0}]}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-9, 9}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: function with an even-order pole]

```
Plot[Sec[x]^2, {x, -3 π, 3 π}, Axes -> True, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], 
                Table[Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}, {(k - 1/2) π, 0}],
                            Scaled[{0, -1}, {(k - 1/2) π, 0}]}], {k, -2, 3}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: multiple poles]

```
Plot[Erf[x], {x, -5, 5}, Axes -> True, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], 
                Line[{Scaled[{1, 0}, {0, 1}], Scaled[{-1, 0}, {0, 1}]}], 
                Line[{Scaled[{1, 0}, {0, -1}], Scaled[{-1, 0}, {0, -1}]}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: error function]

Comment: This technique is still very relevant.  I just had to shade the background inbetween $(x_1, x_2)$ and this seems the best way to do it, with a `Rectangle` in `Prolog` instead of `Line`.

Answer (score 4):

Since Mathematica 10, I prefer [`InfiniteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) for applications like these.  It is more flexible than `GridLines` because it can run in any direction, and it can coexist with, say, `GridLines -> Automatic`.

Example:

```
Plot[1/(x - 1)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}},
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
   InfiniteLine[{1, 0} (* through this point *), {0, 1} (* in a vertical direction *)]},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]