# Show — autorange possible?

Tags: plotting

Given the following simple code:

```
With[{msm = RandomReal[{58., 62.}, 27]},
Manipulate[
 meanval = Mean[msm];
 dif = msm - meanval;
 var = variance[dif];
 sigma = Sqrt[var];
 ulnsigma := meanval + n*sigma;
 llnsigma := meanval - n*sigma;
 Show[
  Plot[{meanval, ulnsigma, llnsigma}, {x, 0, Length[msm] + 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, {Pink, Dashed}, {Pink, Dashed}}, 
   PlotRange -> {Min[msm]*0.99, Max[msm]*1.01}],
  ListLinePlot[msm, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thin, Dashed}]
  ],
 {{n, 1., "n-Sigma"}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 Initialization :> (
   variance[x_] := Total[x^2]/(Length[x] - 1))]
]
```

I have the problem, that `Show` scales the graph according to the first plot in the list, which is disturbing, because the other plots could eventually be out of range and not entirely visible... As you can see, I've also tried to "cheat" it with a `PlotRange` but I'm still not getting the wished results. I would have thought that `Show` should have an "autorange" option, so that it makes all the contained plots visible... or am I missing something?
Here an example, where you cannot see the dashed limit-lines for values of `n` other that 1...

[image]
[image]

Comment: "...`Show` scales the graph according to the first plot in the list, which is disturbing, because the other plots could eventually be out of range and not entirely visible..." - yes, [that's known behavior](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128).

Comment: @J.M. in my opinion it should be described as a "known problem" instead of "known behaviour" :-) . Thanks for the link (wasn't able to find it myself)!

Comment: As you can see from the linked thread, the solution is `Show[..., PlotRange -> All]`.  OK to mark as duplicate?  In principle things can go wrong with this one too (as in showing *too much*), but that doesn't usually happen.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it's indeed a duplicate, sorry...

Comment: No need to be sorry, this stuff is not easy to find.  Just wanted to make sure that it solves your problem before voting.

Comment: I think the easy solution is to not use `Show`, but add the horizontal lines as `Epilog` items to your `ListLinePlot`. I'd work it up as an answer, but I'm pressed for time just now.

Comment: If you want to pursue m_goldberg's approach, you can adapt some of the solutions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118419) to make horizontal lines.

Comment: If you use `Epilog`, look up `InfiniteLine` (@m_goldberg)