# How to build and manipulate 2 surface in one box, so that intersection is highlighted and unwanted parts are removed during movement?

Tags: plotting, visualization

As the title indicates, I want to  build (and manipulate) two three-dimensional surfaces in one bounding box, so that their intersection is highlighted and the unwanted parts of the surfaces are removed during their movement relative to each other.

First of all  I created surface $x=0$ using `ContourPlot3D`. Here is the corresponding code (I used the right tool?):

```
cp1 = ContourPlot3D[x == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
                    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

which produces this output:

[image: plane]

Then I created surface $\cos (x) \sin (y)$ using `Plot3D`. Here is the corresponding code (I used the right tool?):

```
Plot3D[Cos[x]*Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

which produces this output:

[image: surface]

Then I created two three-dimensional surfaces ($\cos (x) \sin (y)$ and $x=0$) in one bounding box. Here is the corresponding code (I used the right tool?):

```
Show[cp1, Plot3D[Cos[x]*Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]]
```

I get this output:

[image: plane and surface]

My question is the following: How can I move (manipulate) the surface $x=0$ along the $x$ axis (no movement along the $y$ and $z$ axes), so that surface $x=0$ would be  cutoff surface for surface  $\cos (x) \sin (y)$ and their intersection is highlighted. Surface  $\cos (x) \sin (y)$ not moving.

If for example (this picture is taken not from Mathematics):

[image: example]

**EDIT**

@JM code is not working:

[image: J. M.'s code]

Comment: The code works in version 10 and 11. If you're using a version older than that, please edit your question to mention the version you are using.

Comment: @JM - I have the program "Mathematica 9"  on my computer . Can I also put "Mathematica 11" on my computer? Can the two versions stand on the same computer?

Comment: @JM - I have 11.2 - it's working!  I delete my 9 version , because Mathematica installer tell me about it!

Comment: sasvak, actually, it's possible to have more than one version of *Mathematica* on a computer. I personally do so to track changes between versions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a starting point:

```
n = 31;
Animate[Show[Plot3D[Cos[x] Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
                    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
                    BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> {{xx}}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
                    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotPoints -> 45, 
                    PlotRange -> {-5, 5}], 
             Graphics3D[InfinitePlane[{xx, 0, 0}, Rest[IdentityMatrix[3]]]]],
        {xx, -5, 5, 10/(n - 1)}]
```

[image: slicing plane]

---

For those working in older versions without `InfinitePlane[]`, use the following instead:

```
Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 1, 1}, {xx, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0, -1, 1}, {xx, 0, 0}],
         Scaled[{0, -1, -1}, {xx, 0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1, -1}, {xx, 0, 0}]}]
```

The technique is quite similar to what I used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118471).

Comment: @JM  Hello! First of all thank you very much! But my Mathematica give me sign ------ orange  "+" in right side -------- Message ---- "InfinitePlane is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive".

Comment: @JM And also surface $x=0$ not drawing, only  intersection line is highlighted and moving

Comment: @JM Also moving sometimes hangs (or freeze)  [link](http://g.recordit.co/waYeubrAc6.gif)

Comment: How did you save the animation?

Comment: @Raffaele. what I actually do for exporting an animation is to use, well, `Export[]` + `Table[]`: `Export["filename.gif", Table[(* stuff *)]]`

Comment: @Raffaele. Right click on picture and choose save graphics as, then choose gif file type

Answer (score 1):

Another way with interactivity, and animation:

```
Manipulate[
Show[
{
Plot3D[{Exp[- 0.09 (x^2 + y^2)] Cos[2 x] Sin[y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{x0}}, 
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.01]], 
PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> {If[u, Opacity[0.8], Opacity[0]]}, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotTheme -> "Business"],

 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Yellow, 
 If[v, Directive[Opacity[0.8]], Directive[Opacity[0]]], 
 InfinitePlane[{x0, 0, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}]
}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .9}
],
{{x0, -1.5}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
Delimiter,
{{u, True, "f[x]"}, {True, False}}, {{v, True, "Cut plane"}, {True, 
False}},
ControlPlacement -> Top
]
```

[image]

Comment: The code works in version 9?

Comment: @sasvak Sorry, I do not know. Just check it !  Anyway, it is possible that some functions regarding the appearance of the plot will belong to later updates if so, or substitute them with  their equivalent. My suggestion is to eliminate them. If some important functions do not work, the code definitely is not for ver 9. Please, when ask a question, indicate the target version of MMA.

Comment: @JADN I have 11.2 - it's working!