# How to draw a Line on a Plot, with a small scale, using Prolog or Epilog

Tags: plotting, graphics

If I want to draw a line on a `Plot` I can use `Prolog` or `Epilog`. However, this goes wrong if the scale of the plot is small. Here is a minimum working example.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Line[{{4, -1}, {4, 1}}]}]
Plot[10^-13 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Line[{{4, -1}, {4, 1}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

No vertical line is drawn in the second case. This is the problem. I guess that it is due to the small scale and the line is not drawn to this resolution. If I change the scale of the vertical line it works

```
Plot[10^-13 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Red, Line[{{4, -10^-13}, {4, 10^-13}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However this requires me to find the scale of the plot first and put this into the line. I am working with the strains from the Finite Element Method within a `Dynamic` and I can't predict the scale in advance. I thought of this

```
Show[Plot[10^-13 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True],
 Graphics[{Red, Line[{{4, -1}, {4, 1}}]}]
 ]
```

However this does not work either. Is it possible to use `Scaled` or `Offset`? I failed when I tried. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for a comment.)

Yes, you can use `Scaled[]`, as I did in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118471). To wit,

```
{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
      Prolog -> {Red, Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}, {4, 0}], Scaled[{0, -1}, {4, 0}]}]}], 
 Plot[1*^-13 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
      Prolog -> {Red, Line[{Scaled[{0, 1}, {4, 0}], Scaled[{0, -1}, {4, 0}]}]}]}
// GraphicsRow
```

[image: vertical line]

Or, you can use `InfiniteLine[]`:

```
Plot[1*^-13 Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Frame -> True, 
     Prolog -> {Red, InfiniteLine[{4, 0}, {0, 1}]}]
```

which should yield the same picture as the one on the right.

Comment: Very helpful thanks. I have never quite understood `Scaled` this is a good example to learn. `InfiniteLine` is more intuitive. All good and helpful, thanks.