# How to exclude multiple ranges from the X-axis in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

Here I have the codes for my Listplot.

```
α[δ_, s13_, s12_, θ12_, 
   c13_] := (-180/2 π  ) ArcTan[
    s13^2 s12^2 Sin[
       2 δ Degree]/(c13^2 Cos[2 θ12 Degree] s12^2 + 
        s13^2 s12^2 Sin[2 δ Degree])];
```

```
Tab1 = Table[{δ, α[δ, 
     Random[Real, {0.1363, 0.157}], Random[Real, {0.5, 0.595}], 
     Random[Real, {30.002, 36.6}], 
     Random[Real, {0.9906, 0.9875}]]}, {δ, 0, 190, 1 Degree}];
```

```
P1 = ListPlot[Tab1, PlotRange -> {-25, 25}, 
  FrameLabel -> {δ, α}, Frame -> True,  PlotStyle -> Red,]
```

[image: It is \alpha vs \delta plot]

Here I want to omit the points from the plot obtained for the ranges of delta {20,50} and {125,150}. Please suggest how do I do that.

Comment: welcome to MMA SE! Your table `Tab1` uses a step size of `1 Degree`. This means that in computing `\[Alpha]`, you wind up with something of units `Degree^2`. Is this intentional? If the bounds 0 and 190 represent degrees, I suspect the step size should be 1.

Comment: `ListPlot[Select[Tab1, Not@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{20, 50}, {125, 150}], First[#]] &]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to change the construction of `Tab1` in the first place, and simply `Join` together the ranges that you are going to keep.

Another is to use `Select`, `Cases`, or `DeleteCases` to modify `Tab1`. With `Select`, one could do that as

```
Select[Tab1, Not[20 <= #[[1]] <= 50] && Not[125 <= #[[1]] <= 150] &]
```

This applies the function in the second argument to each element of the list, and throws away the ones that give `False`, keeping ("selecting") only those that give `True`.

As @Louis B mentioned in a comment, you can also represent the interval as `Interval[{20, 50}, {125, 150}]`, and test for membership via `IntervalMemberQ`. As @Louis B says, the corresponding function to use in the second argument would be `Not @ IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{20,50}, {125,150}], First[#]] &`.

With `DeleteCases`, one could do that as

```
DeleteCases[Tab1, {_?(20 <= # <= 50 || 125 <= # <= 150 &), _}]
```

This deletes all parts of the expression that match the pattern in the second argument, which matches any list of two expressions, the first of which yields true under the function enclosed in parentheses after `?`. Another way to write that pattern is

```
DeleteCases[Tab1, {x_, _} /; (20 <= x <= 50 || 125 <= x <= 150)]
```

where `x` now names the first blank pattern, and `/;` can be read as "on the condition that".

Hope this helps; let me know if anything is unclear or mysterious!

Comment: Where should I write the code for the DeleteCases i.e in the next line of Tab1 or in the same line with tab 1. Or should I write it along with the line of P1

Comment: Anywhere that results in it being used by `ListPlot` in the definition of `P1`! You could write it at the beginning in the def of `Tab1`; you could define `Tab2 = DeleteCases[...];` and use that in `P1`; or you could write it right inside `ListPlot` as `ListPlot[DeleteCases[...], ...]`; etc.

Comment: Thank you so so much. It really worked

Answer (score 3):

thorimur's answer explains various ways to remove parts of input data before plotting.

An alternative approach is to *hide* (rather than *remove*) parts of the data. This can be done by constructing white rectangles with appropriate coordinates and combine them with the  original plot using `Show`:

```
listplot = ListPlot[Tab1, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {-25, 25}, 
   FrameLabel -> {δ, α}, Frame -> True];


hiddenranges = {{20, 50}, {125, 150}};

Show[listplot, Graphics @ {White, 
  Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, {#, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {#2, 0}]] & @@@ hiddenranges}]
```

[image]

Comment: learned the `Scaled` trick (which obviates the need to find vertical coordinates for the rectangles) from [this answer by J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118471/125).