# How to make this graph

Tags: plotting

How to fill colors between GridLines, or to color between different regions on the x-axis, like this graph. Also to add the descriptions inside the plot, and to make the AxesLabels beside and below the plot as
`ln H` and `ln (a/a0)`,  respectively.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using several Plot options. Not sure if this will be enough--maybe you need dynamic computation of some options, but hopefully this will get you started:

```
Plot[
  {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, -1},
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All,
  Prolog -> {LightBrown, Rectangle[{-1, -2}, {3, 2}], LightGreen, Rectangle[{8, -2}, {11, 2}]},
  FrameLabel -> {Log[a/Subscript[a, 0]], Log[H]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.6, .15}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I usually use a device similar to the one [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118471) for background rectangles, whenever I can't be bothered to reckon out vertical ranges: `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, Prolog -> {{LightBrown, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, {0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {3, 0}]]}, {LightGreen, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, {8, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {10, 0}]]}}, FrameLabel -> {Log["a"/Subscript["a", 0]], Log["H"]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.6, .15}]]`

Comment: Nice improvement!

Comment: Many thanks for the answers.